# Python multiprocessing Pool collision (file writing) due to process race-condition

Tags: python, multiprocessing, race-condition

The objective of the code is to read sqlite3 file and process the text and write to another file (gzip format). I am trying to use multiprocessing with pool, but 
sometimes it generates errors and stop with error message "Cannot create a file when that file already exists". After the fail, if I repeat the same code, it works fine most of cases, which means this happens occasionally.

I guess this is related to race between processes in the pool, but cannot find a way to solve the problem. Normally it works nice, but sometimes it causes problem.

Also, I tried to terminate all the process at each directory level, and start new processes in the next directory.

P.S. Environment: Windows server 64bit, Python 2.7 64bit

```
import sqlite3 as lite
import gzip
import multiprocessing

def convert_txt((infile,outfile)):
    try:
        conn=lite.connect(infile)
        conn.text_factory = str
    except:
        print 'Sql Lite error:', infile
        return

    try:
        fout = gzip.open(outfile, 'wb')
    except:
        'File write error:', outfile
        return 

    for line in conn.iterdump():
        fout.write(line.replace('abc','def')

    fout.close()


for directory in directory_list:
    filenames=glob.glob('B:\\Hebercity UT\\*.txt')
    p = multiprocessing.Pool(min(10,len(filenames)))
    file_list=[]
    for input_file in filenames:
        output_file=input_file.replace('.txt','.csv')
        file_list.append([input_file, output_file])
    p.map(convert_txt, file_list)
    time.sleep(1)
    p.close()   # close the pool and start the pool in the next directory



Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "B:\gws_txt_converter_multi.py", line 100, in <module>
    p.map(convert_txt_msg, fflist)
  File "C:\opt\Anaconda\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 251, in map
    return self.map_async(func, iterable, chunksize).get()
  File "C:\opt\Anaconda\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 558, in get
    raise self._value
WindowsError: [Error 183] Cannot create a file when that file already exists: 'B:\\Hebercity UT'
```

Comment: What do your glob strings look like? There aren't any race conditions because `output_file` is generated from unique file names.... unless your glob is picking up other file types so that `replace('.txt','.csv')` doesn't change the name or there is already a `.csv` in the directory.

Comment: Given the error string it is likely that your glob is rather promiscuous and picked up a subdirectory named `B:\\Hevercity UT`.

Comment: Lets try this again. You likely have a directory called `'B
:\\Hebercity UT'`, and you did `glob.glob('B:\\Hebercity UT')`. Care to give any feedback?

Comment: Thanks for the good comments. I haven't tried your suggestions, but I believe that is not related to file name duplication. Because most of cases the code works in the second attempt after the fail, which means this happens irregularly. Actually, I have tried set(filenames) instead of filenames, which produce same result.

Comment: A race condition seems odd. Each filename in output_file should be unique. So there is no chance that the file already exists. Do you know which line causes the trouble? Moreover, you already catch errors at `gzip.open`, so you should not get any aborts at that line. What is the line `fout.write(line.replace('abc','def')` doing exaclty? Is `line` a string or a file or something?